# Deleting occurrences of an element in an array in C

Tags: c, debugging

This C code is for deleting all occurrences of an integer in an array. However, when I executed it, there is a problem with displaying the final array, the code doesn't display the rest of the array once it finds the first occurrence.

```
unsigned int T[10], n, i, j, exist, integerDeleteOccurences;

printf("Array length : ");
scanf("%u", &n);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("T[%u] : ", i);
    scanf("%u", &T[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%u | ", T[i]);
}

printf("The number you want to delete its occurences : ");
scanf("%u", &integerDeleteOccurences);

exist = 0;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (T[i] == integerDeleteOccurences)
    {
        j = i;
        for (j=i; j<n-1; j++);
        {
            T[j] = T[j+1];
        }
        exist = 1;
        i--;
        n--;
    }
}

if (exist == 1)
{
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%u | ", T[i]);
    }
}

else if (exist == 0)
{
    printf("This number doesn't exist in the array ! \n");
}
```

Comment: You don't provide full code, and you are taking input from a stream that is not shown.  There is so much potential for undefined behavior in the details that are omitted that it is nearly impossible to provide a reasonable answer.  Reduce your code so that it is  complete and show the actual data that is used.

Comment: In the code you show, `T` is not initialized, so you have undefined behavior when you attempt to pass `T[0]` to printf, regardless of whether or not the attempt to use the potentially unset value of `n` in the condition of the for loop was defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is far to complicated.

```
size_t removeFromArray(int *arr, size_t size, int val)
{
    int *tail = arr;
    size_t newSize = size;
    if(arr)
    {
        while(size--)
        {
            if(*tail == val) { tail++; newSize--;}
            else 
                *arr++ = *tail++;
        }
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Comment: `if(arr && size)` is redundant: `if(arr)` suffices

Answer (score -1):

When working with **statically allocated arrays** (i.e. you *know* the **maximum possible size**), you should handle them by keeping track of their current size.

Here's a function that delete all occurrencies of an element, given an array and its size, and returns the number of deletions:

```
int deleteAllOccurrencies(int* arr, int size, int el)
{
    int occurrencies = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == el)
        {
            occurrencies++;
            
            // shift following elements
            for (int j = i; j < size; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return occurrencies;
}
```

#### Edit with alternative solution (suggested by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie))

The above function loops through an array of integers and for each occurrency found, removes the element from the array and shifts the following values by one position. However, that is not much efficient, since the time complexity of that approach is **O(n²)**.

A better solution would be to loop through the array by using two indexes:

- `i`, which is used to check each value in the starting array, and is increased at the end of each loop;
- `j`, which is used to update only the array elements that are different from the one want to delete, and is increased *only* when that value is different.

This way we are able to get a much more efficient check, reaching a time complexity of **O(n)**:

```
int deleteAllOccurrencies(int* arr, int size, int el)
{
    int occurrencies = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == el)
        {
            occurrencies++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return occurrencies;
}
```

#### Example Usage

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10

int deleteAllOccurrencies(int* arr, int size, int el);
void printArray(int* arr, int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int array[MAX_SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 2, 10 };
    int size = MAX_SIZE, res;

    printf("Array: ");
    printArray(array, size);

    res = deleteAllOccurrencies(array, size, 2);
    size = MAX_SIZE - res;

    printf("\nResult: %d occurrencies found!\n", res);
    printf("Resulting array: ");
    printArray(array, size);

    return 0;
}

int deleteAllOccurrencies(int* arr, int size, int el)
{
    int occurrencies = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == el)
        {
            occurrencies++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return occurrencies;
}

void printArray(int* arr, int size)
{
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
        if (i < size - 1)
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Your function `deleteAllOccurrencies` works but the time complexity is **O(n²)** whereas you could reduce it to **O(n)** by using a separate index `j` to write to the array: `int deleteAllOccurrencies(int* arr, int size, int el) { for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++) { if (arr[i] == el) { occurrencies++; } else { arr[j++] = arr[i]; } } return occurrencies; }`

Comment: @chqrlie thank you, I've edited the answer to add your solution and tagged you :)